# What is the Telescope Invariant Point?

Tags: earth-observation, antenna, ground-station

I am working on an implementation of an SLR tool. At some points of the [documentation of the CRD format](https://ilrs.cddis.eosdis.nasa.gov/docs/2009/crd_v1.01.pdf) the term **telescope invariant point** shows up. Apparently it's a point on an ILRS antenna system. From what I have got so far it is some (arbitrary?) point of the antenna system which is not known beforehand but has to be determined through observations.

The documentation states

> Note  that  station  transmit  and  receive  times  are  nominally  with  respect  to  the  system  reference  point 
>   (SRP) which will in many cases be the telescope invariant point. This requires a knowledge of both the  transmit delay and receive delay, which is critical for transponder ranging. It is less critical for normal 
>   satellite  (two-way)  ranging  since  errors  in  distributing  the  system  delay  to  these  components  will 
>   cancel.

If the telescope invariant point is coincident with the station reference point (SRP) I do not have to take care of any corrections at this point?

I also do not get the sentence "This requires a knowledge of both the transmit delay and receive delay". In how far could the transmit and receive delay of an antenna system influence a reference point?